# stop all javascript on window un focus

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

by using

`document.webkitVisibilityState == hidden`

I can to stop all javascript animation and resume when

`document.webkitVisibilityState == visible`

is it possible?

I tried with return false; but didn't work, I am looking at a event that pause all javascript execution and the resume back

[test sample](http://jsfiddle.net/mikulgohil/zZhjt/)

this is just a example to get a basic idea what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to stop animations when the window is not visible, try using webkitRequestAnimationFrame. See http://jsfiddle.net/qK5s2/3/